# Can I recover a lost text file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

How can I recover a lost text file in Windows 7?? It has very important information in it and of course, it is gone because of the stupid Windows Update thing....it just automatically closed all of my stuff and restarted my computer!! Would the text file possibly be in the Temp folder in my computer?? I don't know much about this stuff...but I need it. I didn't save the file which makes me think I can never get it back...but I want to make sure.

Thanks.

I was using notepad.

Comment: Notepad text files are not cached anywhere, it is gone unfortunately, change your Windows Update settings so this will not happen again.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11

Comment: i am soooo mad!!

Answer (score 1):

If you did not save your file, it disappeared from memory when you restarted your computer. More heavy duty writing software such as Word has periodical backup regardless of saving or not, but sadly, notepad hasn't.