# How can I restore from a previous hibernation state?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, hibernate, windows-7-backup

I'm trying to restore lost data from **unsaved notepad.exe**s after Windows 7 automatically restarts (dang Windows Update).

Browsing [a](https://superuser.com/q/487400/78897) [couple](https://superuser.com/q/793008/78897) of threads, it seems to be an impossible task. However, I have previously done hibernation just a few hours ago and there's a neat 2.89 GB memory dump at `C:\hiberfil.sys`. I also have a 3.35 GB `C:\pagefile.sys`.

How can I restore to this previous hibernation state?

Alternatively, is there a program that can view `C:\hiberfil.sys` (e.g. viewing through the previous state as though it's a virtual machine)?

---

My Current System Info:
[image: My Current System Info]

`Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update\View update history`:
[image: <code>Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update\View update history</code>]

Comment: Unfortunately, after a Windows update, files on your disk will no longer match things like cached directory contents in the saved hibernate file. You would have to have some way of putting the disk back to the *exact* state it was in when the hibernation occurred. And if you did that, the machine would just come up and restore state from that file. 
Your long-term answer is to use a note-taking app that automatically saves everything.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan, There had got to be a way to open that file on a virtual machine or something since I know the exact bytes (version) that represents my Windows right now and before the Windows updates.

Comment: The hibernation file doesn't contain your data, its a placeholder file, in order to reserve the space required to hibernate your system.

Comment: @Ramhound, The hibernation file is simply a frost of the RAM right? And the unsaved notepads are stored in the RAM. Why is restoration not possible?

Comment: @Pacerier - Because the file you see isn't from your last hibernation state that was already been discarded when you did the reboot.  As I said the file you see is reserving the space for the next time you hibernate

Comment: @Ramhound, Why do you say that it's discarded if Windows Explorer is reporting the file size as 3.35 GB? Do you mean that the actual bytes are overridden? If so, what would they be overridden with? I've not done any special settings like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\ClearPageFileAtShutdown` or the sort.

Comment: Why would a registry key with regards to the page file effect the hibernation file.  **All I know is your file isn't in the hibernation file.**

Comment: @Ramhound, it is not the case that hiberfil.sys is overwritten once it's been resumed from. It is written only when you hibernate the system. Otherwise forensic inspection of the hibernate file would not be a useful technique (and it is; see http://www.securityweek.com/microsoft-windows-sleep-feature-poses-security-risk )

Comment: Nevertheless, restarting from the saved hiberfil is not going to work, for the reason I gave before. @Pacerier, you can try putting the changed files back but you will never get all the FS metadata back to the previous state. I have seen reports of people who tried it; the restarted system stayed up for a few seconds and blue-screened. Some of your Notepads' data IS likely in that file, and if you inspect the file with a "file dump" tool you can see it... but it will be hugely fragmented, not all in one place. Good luck finding it among gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no way that takes less than a week (or maybe month) to restore file like this.

1. As far I know - hiberfil.sys is compressed and not well documented. Long time ago there was a tool to read windows 2000 hiberfil.sys, it was called SandMan. I think this will not work with Windows 6.0 and higher.
2. Even if you manage to reproduce raw memory that was dumped into hiberfil.sys - do not expect you will find your file there. Process memory will be fragmented, so you would have to put everything together to make it "readable" like process memory dump from Task Manager. Which is not very readable too.